# Android good activity/fragment communication practices - GPS

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, gps, android-fragmentactivity

I have a single activity with a lot of fragments and the trouble of efficient fragment-activity communication comes up quite often. I've implemented a location tracking service in my activity following this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Now I have to pass the device location to my many fragments. I've resorted to the typical getActivity() call from fragment, to call the location returning methods of my activity. This call however proves to be problematic at times, since it's bound to return null at random occasions. I understand that it is conditioned with the fragment being detached from the activity, but since there is no obvious pattern that would tell when that happens, I'm not sure how to fix it. All I can do is check if the activity is null, but that would probably prevent me from getting the location.

There is another solution proposed at this link http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity but I am not sure whether it would work any better than my inital code.

How would I go about solving this? Any tips and help would be appreciated.

Comment: the developer guide works well in all circumstances I had a single activity and 35+ fragments in my application. I had about 25 interfaces in that single activity. It was mainly due to navigation drawer as I needed it in all activity

Comment: A similar situation over here. I am also using the navigation drawer and am therefore resorting to a single activity. I really detest duplicating code through too many activities. Thanks for the tip, I'll give it a go with the interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically I've done as Illegal Argument suggested and implemented interfaces for individual fragments. It's true that the code has grown in size, but it's totally worth the correct communication handling. No more null pointers on getActivity() calls :)

Developer guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity